# Can a laptop with a Core I5-7200U be limited to 16GB RAM max?

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, memory-limit

I recently bought a new laptop, a HP ProBook 430 G4 with an Intel I5-7200U CPU and 8GB RAM. The laptop has two RAM slots and was delivered with a single 8GB 2133 MHz / PC4-17000 SO-DIMM. I've upgraded it to 16GB with a second 8GB SO-DIMM. The specs for this laptop say that it can be upgraded to 16GB, but other laptops with the same CPU and chipset can be upgraded to 32GB.

So, if the chipset and CPU support 32GB RAM, can the motherboard limit this to 16GB max? I haven't opened the laptop to look at the motherboard, and I haven't found the motherboard specified yet. What else may HP have done to limit the maximum supported RAM of this laptop to only 16GB? Both the RAM slots are available, so I can easily replace both units with single 16GB SO-DIMMs.

I haven't got two 16GB SO-DIMMs available to try, has anyone else tried?

Comment: Whether a particular motherboard supports a particular size of DIMM is a matter of trial and error. You can try it, and if it doesn't work then return the memory.

Comment: So referring to the linked "duplicate", if 25 address lines are routed on the motherboard then 32GB RAM should be supported, but if only 24 address lines are routed then the limit is 16GB. I'll see what I can find out about the motherboard.